# Install multiple R versions on MacOS Catalina (version 10.15.2)

Tags: r, macos, macos-catalina

Before upgrading my MacBook Pro (early 2015) to macOS catalina 10.15.2, I can install multiple versions of R by first running some commands like this:

```
sudo pkgutil --forget org.r-project.R.mavericks.fw.pkg
sudo pkgutil --forget org.r-project.R.mavericks.GUI.pkg 
sudo pkgutil --forget org.r-project.R.mavericks.GUI64.pkg
```

But under Catalina 10.15.2, the above commands didn't work any more. The following error was shown:

> No receipt for 'org.r-project.R.mavericks.fw.pkg' found at '/'.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can go to Terminal and run `pkgutil --pkgs` to see what are the current names for the installed packages. Then you can follow the instructions [here](https://jacobrprice.github.io/2019/09/19/Installing-multiple-parallel-R-versions.html) provided by Jake Price (super helpful).

For example, when I run `pkgutil --pkgs` on my MacOS Big Sur I see:

> org.R-project.R.fw.pkg

If I use a wrong name in my Terminal, for example, `org.r-project.R.fw.pkg`, it will return:

> No receipt for 'org.r-project.R.fw.pkg' found at '/'.

The forget command works when I use

> `sudo pkgutil --forget org.R-project.R.fw.pkg \`.

You just have to find all 4 R files and use the forget command line for all of them.